# MongoDB WriteError "code" : 9

Tags: mongodb, write-error

I am trying to delete some records from MongoDB that have dirty values, but whenever I try to delete it, I am getting the **writeError** with **code 9**.

A sample of the dirty document is as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : "some_unique_id_abcd",
    "tmp" : "1415772407377",
    "hiv" : "0.0",
    "liv" : "0.0",
    "oindx" : "0.0"
}
```

The  remove command executed is as follows:

```
db.myCollection.remove({"_id" : "some_unique_id_abcd"});
```

The following error is thrown

```
WriteResult({
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 9,
        "errmsg" : "wrong type for 'delete' field, expected string, 
                    found delete: 0.0"
    }
})
```

Any idea what exactly this error is about or how to get around it?

Comment: Is it a capped collection?

Comment: Please post the actual code that you execute to remove the document, and the original document as is in the database. Are you using any javasctipt client APIs or simply executing the command via the shell?

Comment: I am using Mongo Client and running native commands to delete the document using the code posted above. Its a standard Mongo Command. 
All I want to know is what exactly the code:9 represents and why it is happening?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/ - FYI. My answer was based on your assumption that it was a capped collection.

Comment: I understand. It would be really helpful if you can explain the code:9 and  when exactly does it occur. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/50dc6dbe394c42d03659aa3410954f1e3ff46740/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err#L12) is what the error code means:

```
error_code("FailedToParse", 9)
```

Comment: Thanks @anhlc for the exact answer that I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

From the capped collection docs that BatScream linked:

> You cannot delete documents from a capped collection. To remove all
>   records from a capped collection, use the ‘emptycapped’ command. To
>   remove the collection entirely, use the drop() method.

Documents expire from the capped collection as new documents are inserted. You cannot manually delete documents. See the docs for more info and warnings about capped collections.

Comment: As discussed previously, its not a capped collection.

Comment: You did not say that. Can you post your full code that produces the error? What version of shell and server are you using? I don't reproduce this behavior with that document and that remove command with MongoDB 2.6.4 and the 2.6.4 shell.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not share the actual code as its protected by NDA. Also, you can not reproduce it! :(

It would really help if you can tell me what exactly the  "code" : 9 stands for and when does MongoDB report this error. The rest I can then figure out myself.