# writeError code 9 when attempting to remove multiple docs

Tags: mongodb

running the following code in the mongo console (3.0.8):

```
db.collection.remove({"_id": {"$in": [ObjectId("573e01c47b031db251bc2e7f")]}})
```

produces this error:

```
{
    "writeError" : {
            "code" : 9,
            "errmsg" : "wrong type for 'q' field, expected object, found q: [ { _id: ObjectId('573e01c47b031db251bc2e7f') } ]"
    }
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26966437/mongodb-writeerror-code-9) answer says it's a `FailedToParse` error, but doesn't say why that's happening or how to fix it.

EDIT:
I should add the collection is not capped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using wrong variable in query :P